# Unable to install MongoDB.Driver version 2.11.2 in SSIS project

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, ssis, nuget

I have a script task in my SSIS project using MongoDB drivers. I tried to install MongoDB.Driver version 2.11.2 in the script task C# project but on rebuilding I'm getting the following error

**This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.1.0.0\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.targets.    ST_7e8a155c666a4ff9b020c07cdb8e724e C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_ST150\Vsta1bvb5z9jtk__jBvgTVAuC6g\Vsta8nCJn9QlcUus__KZ_hX0ZLg\ST_7e8a155c666a4ff9b020c07cdb8e724e.csproj 170**

But When I checked the path mentioned in the error message, I found that the file is already there and somehow its got ignored while rebuilding.

To verify whether it's related to SSIS, I created another class project which is not part of the SSIS project and installed the same driver and there it's working perfectly.

Do I need to do anything extra in SSIS to include the mongo library?. I'm new to SSIS so please point me to the right path

Comment: You can open the csproj with notepad and compare version in csproj with actual version.  Or delete object from project and add again so version is updated.

Comment: @jdweng I did that and there is no version difference

Comment: Is there a executable in the project bin folder?  Is it in the release or debug folder?

Comment: Consuming Nuget package is not supported in SSIS Script task. You can download the Nuget and add reference to the dlls. Please refer the JIRA ticket raised https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3275